# How to set ImageResizer configuration programmatically?

Tags: c#, config, imageresizer

I want to set the configuration parameter `clientcache.minutes`programmatically but im struggling with the config design in ImageResizer.

My approach currently is:

```
var lWebConfigReader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(@"Web.config");

var lXmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
lXmlDocument.Load(lWebConfigReader);

var lResizerNode = lXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/resizer");

var lSection = new ImageResizer.ResizerSection(lResizerNode.OuterXml);

var lConfig = new ImageResizer.Configuration.Config(lSection);

int mins = lConfig.get("clientcache.minutes", -1);

...

ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.setConfigXml(lConfig.getConfigXml());
```

It seems a bit hacky and also doesn't work as the `ClientCache` plugin doesn't sent the `Expires` header as it normally should when `clientcache.minutes` is set.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging in the source code i found out that in this particular case you need to alter the global configuration object as the `ClientCache` plugin reads the parameter via `Get()` from it. So my current solution is:

```
// read a XML where a <resizer>...</resizer> is present, in this case a typical Web.config as mentioned in the ImageResizer docs
var lWebConfigReader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(@"Web.config");

var lXmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
lXmlDocument.Load(lWebConfigReader);

// read the resizer tag to a node
var lResizerNode = lXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/resizer");

// create a section from the node
var lSection = new ImageResizer.ResizerSection(lResizerNode.OuterXml);

// create a new config object from the section
var lConfig = new ImageResizer.Configuration.Config(lSection);

// override the global configugration with the newly created one
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.setConfigXml(lConfig.getConfigXml());

// test the Get() call used by the ClientCache plugin
int mins = ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.get("clientcache.minutes", -1);
```

This code could be placed in a `ICurrentConfigProvider` implementation or `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax`.